# AWS Lambda Function URL - CORS Allow origin is not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I am trying to allow requests to my Lambda Function URL only from my specific URL and only for POST methods.

Here is my Lambda Function URL configuration:

[image: Lambda Function URL configuration]

Here is the Lambda function content:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!!')
    }
```

Problems:

1. When I go to the function URL on my browser I see "Hello from
   Lambda!!". Considering it is a GET call I shouldn't see the result
   right?
2. When I call the function URL with HTTP POST method from my Angular App (origin: localhost:4200), I am getting CORS error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." But I added that header to my request as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Angular request screenshot]

I tried 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' as well but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"When I go to the function URL on my browser I see "Hello from Lambda!!". Considering it is a GET call I shouldn't see the result right?"* - no, CORS is handled by the browser if you have a cross origin request. If you just hit that URL by e.g. entering it in the address bar and hitting enter there is no cross origin request happening, CORS is not involved.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, in that case if I return error when I don't receive the required parameters by POST method, I can secure this URL invoking, correct?

Comment: The CORS headers have to be added to the *response* by the *backend*. Ie adding them to the *request* is useless ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution.

As seen in the screenshot below, I added the same headers to Expose Headers in Lambda Function URL config. This way, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error is gone, since they are now exposed to the requester.

[image: Lambda Function URL config]

I'm still open to suggestions about whether I should change those allowed and exposed headers, if all is not required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for my first, wrong answer, read the question incorrectly)

Your suggestion to add the headers in the "Exposed Header" field is the right thing. And then you (generally) also have to add it to the response of your lambda, otherwise it won't be there.

```
return {
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": response_body,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:4200",
    },
}
```

Docs: While the general docs are a bit vague/empty here, the API Reference is actually quite informative:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Cors.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunctionUrlConfig.html

Comment: Thanks Blitz. I think what you say is correct for ApiGateway + Lambda functions. When I added headers to the Lambda response, I got an error saying something like "There is a duplication in your response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": " *, * ". I believe it is because the Function URL of Lambda already sends the header from the "Allow origins" option. So now it works for me without sending a single header from the Lambda response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is not throwing an error as if your lambda is raising an exception then it is possible that the header will not be present when returned.